# In Perl, what is the meaning of if (s/^\+//)?

Tags: regex, perl, perltk

In a Perl/Tk code I found a conditional statement as below

```
if (s/^\+//)
{
   #do something
}
elsif (/^-/)
{
   #do another thing
}
```

Seems like some pattern matching has been done. But I cannot understand it. Can anyone help me understanding this pattern matching?

Comment: @Oded, that link isn't the worst Perl tutorial I've ever seen, but it is rather old and uses a few outdated practices (`-w` vs `warnings`, prototypes). I might recommend [`perldoc perlretut`](http://p3rl.org/retut).

Comment: @JoelBerger - Fair enough. It was the first hit off google.

Comment: @Oded, NP. The longevity of Perl tutorials is something the community is trying to fight by making/highlighting newer better ones, and warning about old/bad ones http://perl-tutorial.org/. Perl got a bad name after the dot-com boom brought in lots of bad code, we're trying to make it better one tutorial at a time.

Comment: I've added that tutorial to the legacy tutorials list on http://perl-tutorial.org. It spends quite a bit too much time on some old syntax, but it does a decent job of touching on the new. It not bad, but not the best for a beginner.

Comment: What did you do to try and understand this code? The documentation that comes with Perl is *really* comprehensive. What stopped you from finding the answers there?

Answer (score 12):

They are both regular expressions. You can read up on them at [perlre](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html) and [perlretut](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlretut.html). You can play around with them on [http://www.rubular.com](http://www.rubular.com/r/CEtqZ3YUIi).

They both implicitly do something with `$_`. There probably is a `while` or `foreach` around your lines of code without a loop variable. In that case, `$_` becomes that loop variable. It might for instance contain the current line of a file that is being read.

1. If the current value of `$_` contains a `+` (plus) sign as the first character at the beginning of the string, `#do somehting`.
2. Else if it contains a `-` (minus) sign, `#do another thing`.

In case 1. it also replaces that `+` sign with nothing (i.e. removes it). It does not remove the `-` in 2. however.

---

Let's look at an explanation with [YAPE::Regex::Explain](https://metacpan.org/module/YAPE%3a%3aRegex%3a%3aExplain).

```
use YAPE::Regex::Explain;
print YAPE::Regex::Explain->new(qr/^\+/)->explain();
```

Here it is. Not really helpful in our case, but a nice tool nonetheless. Note that the `(?-imsx` and `)` parts are the default things Perl implies. They are always there unless you change them.

```
The regular expression:

(?-imsx:^\+)

matches as follows:

NODE                     EXPLANATION
----------------------------------------------------------------------
(?-imsx:                 group, but do not capture (case-sensitive)
                         (with ^ and $ matching normally) (with . not
                         matching \n) (matching whitespace and #
                         normally):
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  ^                        the beginning of the string
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  \+                       '+'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
)                        end of grouping
----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

---

**Update**: As Mikko L in the comments pointed out, you should maybe refactor/change this piece of code. While it probably does what it is supposed to, I believe it would be a good idea to make it more readable. Whoever wrote it obviously didn't care about you as the later maintainer. I suggest you do. You could change it to:

```
# look at the content of $_ (current line?)
if ( s/^\+// )
{
  # the line starts with a + sign,
  # which we remove!

  #do something
}
elsif ( m/^-/ )
{
  # the line starts witha - sign
  # we do NOT remove the - sign!

   #do another thing
}
```

Comment: Your analysis is spot-on. I would add that the OP should consider refactoring this piece of code so that the substitution is more obvious. It's very easy to miss it the way it's written now. Even simply going to `if( /^\+/ ) { $_ =~ s/^\+//; # do something }` would help considerably.

Comment: @MikkoL I agree and added the suggestions. I do not agree with the explicit use of `$_`, but that is personal preference I believe. Thank you.

Comment: Downvoter, do you care to comment on how I can improve my post?

Comment: I'm not such a big fan of this refactoring.  It adds another pattern match, and pattern matches can be quite expensive in some cases.  It is also a pretty normal Perl idiom to use `if (s/.../.../)` to check whether a substitution took place. If you're worried about clarity, a comment would do fine (Note: I'm not the downvoter--the answer is good overall).

Comment: I agree with dan, there's no reason not to `s///` to both match and remove a marker. This is why patterns return the number of matches/substitutions in a scalar context.

Comment: In general I also agree. I did think Mikko L's comment was good, though. I decided to go with it because the OP obviously isn't very strong with Perl, so I thought the helpfulness of the explicit variant with the extra match outweighs the cost of that other match. I'll change it.

Answer (score 5):

Those are regular expressions, used for pattern matching and substitution.

You should read up on the concept, but as for your question:

```
s/^\+//
```

If the string started with a plus, remove that plus (the "s" means "substitute"), and return true.

```
/^-/
```

True if the string starts with a minus.

Answer (score 3):

This code is equivalent to

```
if ($_ =~ s/^\+//) {  # s/// modifies $_ by default
   #do something
}
elsif ($_ =~ m/^-/) {  # m// searches $_ by default
   #do another thing
}
```

`s///` and `m//` are regexp quote-like operators. You can read about them in [perlop](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Regexp-Quote-Like-Operators).

Comment: This is a perfectly good (though short) answer. I don't see why it was downvoted.

Comment: I didn't downvote, but I'm sure its because, the implicit variable isn't at question here, but rather the substitution pattern itself.

Answer (score 2):

The other answers have given a summary of how the code works, but not much of why. Here is a simple example of why one might use such logic.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my $args = {};

for ( @ARGV ) {
  if ( s/^no// ) {
    $args->{$_} = 0;
  } else {
    $args->{$_} = 1;
  }
}

use Data::Dumper;
print Dumper $args;
```

When you call the script like

```
./test.pl hi nobye
```

you get

```
$VAR1 = {
          'hi' => 1,
          'bye' => 0
        };
```

The key is the string, however if it is preceded by `no` then remove it (to get the key in question) and instead set the value to `0`.

The OP's example is a little more involved, but follows the same logic.

- if the key starts with a `+`, remove it and do something
- if the key starts with a `-`, don't remove it and do something else